# Displaying an image using React

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I'm a totally newbie with `React`, but I think it's the way to develop web applications, so I'm making the effort to learn.

*** login.js: ***

```
var ImageFrame = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div className="bg-pic">
            <img src={"assets/img/demo/new-york-city-buildings-sunrise-morning-hd-wallpaper.jpg"} data-src="assets/img/demo/new-york-city-buildings-sunrise-morning-hd-wallpaper.jpg" data-src-retina="assets/img/demo/new-york-city-buildings-sunrise-morning-hd-wallpaper.jpg" alt="" className="lazy" />
            <div className="bg-caption pull-bottom sm-pull-bottom text-white p-l-20 m-b-20">
              <h2 className="semi-bold text-white">
                        HelloWorld makes the world look easy.
              </h2>
              <p className="small">
                All work copyright of respective owner, HelloWorld Inc.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ImageFrame />,
    document.getElementById('image_container')
);
```

*** login.html ***

```
<body class="fixed-header">
    <div id="image_container" class="login-wrapper"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="assets/js/login.js"></script>
</body>
```

The purple background for the image is displayed, but not the image itself ... when I place the `HTML` version it works just fine:

*** HTML ****

```
<div class="bg-pic">
   <!-- START Background Pic-->
   <img src="assets/img/demo/new-york-city-buildings-sunrise-morning-hd-wallpaper.jpg" data-src="assets/img/demo/new-york-city-buildings-sunrise-morning-hd-wallpaper.jpg" data-src-retina="assets/img/demo/new-york-city-buildings-sunrise-morning-hd-wallpaper.jpg" alt="" class="lazy">
   <!-- END Background Pic-->
   <!-- START Background Caption-->
   <div class="bg-caption pull-bottom sm-pull-bottom text-white p-l-20 m-b-20">
   <h2 class="semi-bold text-white">
       HelloWorld makes the world look easy.</h2>
   <p class="small">
       All work copyright of respective owner, HelloWorld Inc.
   </p>
   </div>
   <!-- END Background Caption-->
</div>
```

How can I get to display the image using `ReactJS`?

Comment: Use require for src src={require("assets/img/demo/new-york-city-buildings-sunrise-morning-hd-wallpaper.jpg")}

Comment: Maybe dropping the curly brackets `{}` from your src attribute, those are used for evaluating a jsx expression.

Comment: @RobbertvanElk ... how about the `data-src` tags?

Comment: @Stefan.B dropping the `{}` didn't solve the problem :-(

Comment: Doesnt it work with require for data-src?

Comment: @RobbertvanElk how would I write the `data-src` tag in react?

Comment: @RobbertvanElk nothing works in making the image to be rendered ... any suggestions?

Comment: and if you put ./ in front of the src string like this: ./assets/img/demo/new-york-city-buildings-sunrise-morning-hd-wallpaper.jpg or what the correct path to assets is from your file

Comment: @RobbertvanElk I tried that one too :-(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are closing tags correctly in the `render`; it looks like the top `<div>` and `img` tags have no closing markers. Is your console giving any errors?

**edit:**
This is rendering ok in a pen with a sample image: http://codepen.io/kiresuah/pen/JRYGJL?editors=1010, I suspect it has something to do with your static file structure or how you are importing the image.

Comment: Erik, when i gave the image's full path in the src `http://localhost:8080/html/assets/img/demo/new-york-city-buildings-sunrise-morning-hd-wallpaper.jpg` it still didn't work.

Comment: the codepen is using react & react-dom 15.3.1, and transpiling through babel - any differences from your setup?